# Catkin migration dynamic reconfigure

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm migrating a project from rosbuild to catkin, and I'm having some problems with the files using dynamic reconfigure.
Currently I'm trying to make the package "controller" which contains a configuration file called dynconfig.cfg.

I followed the migration tutorial to adapt my files, so here's what I did:

- Removed `import roslib;roslib.load_manifest(PACKAGE)` in the .cfg file
- Changed `from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator import *` to `from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *` in the .cfg file
- Added `generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(cfg/dynconfig.cfg)` to my CMakeLists.txt
- Added the `dynamic_reconfigure` dependencies (as run_depend and build_depend in the package.xml as well as in `find_package` and `catkin_package` in the CMakeLists)
- Added `add_dependencies(controller controller_controller)` in the CMakeLists. I'm not quite sure if this is right. I have an executable called controller in the package controller. However, I don't think that's where the error comes from.

Here's the error I get:

```
> make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/home/bic039/catkin_ws/src/controller/cfg/dynconfig.cfg', needed by `/home/bic039/catkin_ws/devel/include/controller/dynconfigConfig.h'.  Stop.
```

Does anybody have an idea where this error might come from? I've been stuck on this issue for quite a while.

Cheers, Rob

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89641/catkin-migration-dynamic-reconfigure/) by [Rob](https://answers.ros.org/users/7636/rob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-10-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you remember this?

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS dynamic_reconfigure)
```

Assuming your node is named "controller", the dependencies should look more like:

```
add_dependencies(controller ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

See the [catkin dynamic reconfigure how-to](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/howto/dynamic_reconfiguration.html) for details.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2